# Filling a parameter pack by skipping optional arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm writing a helper function for logging purposes: it collects call-site
information while also creating a `Error`-typed object.

```cpp
template<typename ErrorTy, typename... ArgTys>
std::unique_ptr<Error> makeError(const char* fileName = __builtin_FILE(),
        int lineNum = __builtin_LINE(),
        const char* funcName = __builtin_FUNCTION(), ArgTys &&... args) {
    return std::make_unique<ContextualError<ErrorTy>>(fileName, lineNum, funcName,
            std::forward<ArgTys>(args)...);
}

// ...

template<typename ErrorTy>
struct ContextualError : ErrorTy {
    template<typename... ArgTys>
    ContextualError(std::string_view fileName, int lineNum,
            std::string_view funcName, ArgTys &&... args) :
            fileName_(fileName), lineNum_(lineNum), funcName_(funcName),
            ErrorTy(std::forward<ArgTys>(args)...) {}

    // ...
};
```

As the actual `Error` classes can have arbitrary constructors, I was hoping to
get `makeError` and the `ContextualError` constructor to perfectly forward
everything. Unfortunately, calling `makeError` like this will try to fill the
first three optional arguments, rather than skipping them and filling the
parameter pack:

```cpp
auto err = makeError<FileError>("foo.exe", "Invalid header");

// error: no matching function for call to 'makeError'
// note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion
//       from 'const char [15]' to 'int' for 2nd argument

// It's trying to replace the default values:
auto err = makeError<FileError>(fileName: "foo.exe", lineNum: "Invalid header", funcName: __builtin_FUNCTION(), args...: );

// But I only want to supply the parameter pack args:
auto err = makeError<FileError>(fileName: __builtin_FILE(), lineNum: __builtin_LINE(), funcName: __builtin_FUNCTION(), args...: "foo.exe", "Invalid header");
```

Moving the parameter pack to the front of the arguments list doesn't seem to fix
this either. Is there any way to achieve this perfect forwarding while keeping
the optional arguments?

[Minimum reproducible example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/S-6-ev)

Comment: How do you want to specify in a call that the default arguments are to be replaced?

Comment: @walnut There shouldn't be any situation where they are replaced: the idea is that they get filled in by the compiler with those built-ins. I wanted to do something along the lines of `#define LOG(...) log(__LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)`, but with modern C++ instead, and it seems these built-ins are the only way (until C++20, but it's more or less the same approach).

Comment: Ah ok, you want to have them in the default arguments, because they wouldn't provide values referring to the call site otherwise. I didn't realize that at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<class ErrorTy>
auto makeError(
    const char* fileName = __builtin_FILE(),
    int lineNum = __builtin_LINE(),
    const char* funcName = __builtin_FUNCTION()
) {
  return [=](auto&&... args) {
    return std::make_unique<ContextualError<ErrorTy>>(
      fileName, lineNum, funcName,
      decltype(args)(args)... // yes, this perfect fowards
    );
  };
}
```

use is:

```
auto err = makeError<FileError>()("foo.exe", "Invalid header");
```

see the extra `()`.  The optional arguments go in `()`, and the forwarded arguments go into the second set of `()`.

[Live example based off yours](https://godbolt.org/z/KfHqsF).

you could also make `makeError` a `class` and give it an `operator()` that makes the actual error, and give it default arguments for its ctor.  Then you'd get:

```
auto err = makeError<FileError>{}("foo.exe", "Invalid header");
```

which might be less confusing, or more confusing.  One of those.

Comment: Creative approach! Doesn't feel 100% right, but that's probably as good as it's gonna get